# shell "No such file or directory" on variable execution result

Tags: sh

some basic function with goal to extract xml var by xpath:

```
function get_xml_value_from_config_dir {
 local src_root=$1
 local xpath_expr="//$2/text()"
 local path_to_local="$src_root/app/etc/local.xml"
 if [ ! -f $path_to_local ]; then echo "Config file not found: $path_to_local"; exit; fi;
 echo $("$xmllint --nocdata --xpath '$xpath_expr' $path_to_local")
}

## and then
src_usr=$(get_xml_value_from_config_dir $src_dir username)
```

gives me

> line 34: /usr/bin/xmllint --nocdata --xpath '//username/text()' /tmp/bin/app/etc/local.xml: No such file or directory

why? ( `/usr/bin/xmllint` exist as well as `/tmp/bin/app/etc/local.xml` )

Comment: Why are you using `echo $("")`? Don't you just want to either echo or run?

Comment: how can i return result of execution of this string ?

Comment: I don't think that is your issue. `xmllint` is a program? Why are you using it as a variable within a string? `$xmllint`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's telling you it can't find the file or directory named

```
/usr/bin/xmllint --nocdata --xpath '//username/text()' /tmp/bin/app/etc/local.xml
```

which indeed is unlikely to exist on your system.
Replace

```
echo $("$xmllint --nocdata --xpath '$xpath_expr' $path_to_local")
```

with

```
echo $($xmllint --nocdata --xpath "$xpath_expr" $path_to_local)
```

Incidentally, that will put all `xmllint` output on a single line; to avoid that, just use

```
xmllint --nocdata --xpath "$xpath_expr" $path_to_local
```

Comment: exactly that was the reason many thanks ! so `$("...")` are trying to execute the path given in quotes ?

Comment: Exactly. The quotes make it one word to the shell.

Comment: Quoting (`echo "$(...)"`) would fix the one line problem, but it is still redundant (and in the case of trailing newlines in the output, lossy) to capture the output of a command just to use it as the sole argument to `echo`.